# Deploy build from Visual Studio Online

Tags: deployment, iis-7.5, azure-devops

I am trying to do a deploy from my visual studio online account to a Remote IIS machine ( and not an Azure Website).Now, i have already achieved deployment to 'azure website' using the tfsvccontinuousDeployment template and to a remote iis using ms deploy parameters .

TFS 2013 comes with release management, but from what i understand,,uts not avaialable on visualstudio online

What i am trying to achieve is a way to deploy the build to the remote iis without using the ms deploy parameters on check in ,somehting like the features on Inrelase

Comment: I don't believe this is possible with VSO, you'd need TFS.

Comment: hmm. i hope they add the feature soon. till then guess, i have to do it via ms deploy parameters

Comment: Is this still not possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can deploy from VSO to dedicated IIS yes. I have been doing this successfully for years (including DBs - currently with SSDTs, previously with the older "Database projects").

But am wondering exactly what you mean by "without using the ms deploy parameters on check in"

Comment: An example perhaps? I have the same problem, after building all solutions in **/Branch/*.sln I want to add a deploy step that will use the publish settings I have been using from VS that use MSDeploy ... but if there's a simpler way to do it without MSDeploy, i'd like to hear it!